# hyperref links not working with enumerate

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, enumerate

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsproc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{T1}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
  \end{enumerate}
  Link on page 2.
\end{theorem}
\newpage By Theorem~\ref{T1}.

\end{document}
```

The hyperlink to Theorem 1 on page 2 does not work when compiled as follows:

```
> latex MWE.tex; dvipdf MWE.dvi; evince MWE.pdf&
```

However, the link does work (but changes magnification from large to 62.34%) if compiled as follows:

```
 > pdflatex MWE.tex; evince MWE.pdf &
```

Finally, if \item is commented out, then both compilation methods give an active link which does not change magnification.

**Question:** Is there a simple way to avoid a dead link or a magnification-changing link?

Comment: are you really using `dvipdf`? If you are using such a backend you will probably have to tell hyperref with `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{hyperref}`. But imho the link will never work correctly see https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/48. (I have no idea what you mean by magnification).

Comment: Not sure this is related to your problem,   but as a general rule, `hyperef` should be loaded last, with very few exceptions.

Comment: @Ulrich Fischer. Evince is a pdf viewer that comes with Ubuntu. It allows you to view pdf files at different magnifications with standard magnifications ranging from 50% to 400%.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[pdfstartview=]{hyperref}` with pdflatex. And my name is Ulrike.

Comment: @Ulrike. I inserted this command on the second line. If I have an evince opened on MWE.pdf at magnification 175% for example, then clicking on the Theorem 1 link changes the magnification to an unreadable 62.34% as before. So this sadly is not a solution.

Comment: I already mentioned the issue: the link doesn't work at all. It simply goes back to page one, it is only luck that your theorem is on page one too. If you would do `\begin{theorem}leavevmode\label{T1}` it will behave.

Comment: @Ulrike. Thanks. Using \leavevmode solves the problem. Also, adding at least one character after \label{T1} and before enumerate, means that \leavevmode is not needed. If you list his as an answer, I can accept it.